# Как правильно: рОстыка или рАстыка?

Tags: орфография, выбор-слов

Это, собственно, вопрос. Говорят ли в вашей местности "растыка" и, если говорят, то как в точности?
[**Пишут**](https://pikabu.ru/story/rastyika_2006394), что в Волгограде слово распространено. Я вырос точно посередине между Ростовом-на-Дону и Волгоградом, впервые услыхал слово в [**мультфильме**](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xnXJnNK6-h8&t=474s).

Comment: Мнения по современной географии употребления:
http://forum.lingvolive.com/thread/l86929/
http://expert.ru/2015/04/18/v-volgograde-govoryat-rastyika/
https://lord-dime.livejournal.com/66461.html

Comment: Спасибо, видимо чисто волгоградское и астраханское слово. Остаётся только удивляться, как оно попало в мультфильм.

Answer (score 2):

[**РАСТЫКА**](https://lopatin.academic.ru/123979/%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8B%D0%BA%D0%B0) (Русский орфографический словарь)

Синонимы:  бестолочь, неумеха, пенек, растыкень, растяпа, шестерка.
[**Словарь синонимов**](https://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/dic_synonims/235563/%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8B%D0%BA%D0%B0)

Растыка – неуклюжий человек (Волгоградская область).
[**Языки русских городов, областей и краев**](https://mi3ch.livejournal.com/2871353.html)

Мне кажется, что слово образовалось от второго значения глагола *растыкать*:
разместить, засунуть беспорядочно, кое-как по разным местам.
*Растыкать вещи по углам.*

*С трудом отведя глаза от красивого женского тела, я хлопнул резинкой своих «семейников» и нырнул с разбега. Трусы едва не снесло водой. Хорош бы я был! С голой-то задницей! **Растыка**...*
О. Языков. Гром и молния

*Я никогда в жизни не видел, чтобы веселье на человеческом лице так внезапно сменялось свирепостью.

— Что?! — заорал Джордж, вскакивая. — Нет, что за **растыка**! Поосторожней нельзя? Какого черта ты не идешь одеваться на берег? Тебе в лодке вообще нечего делать! Давай багор, быстро...*
Джером К. Джером (перевод Г. Севера)

В нашей (эстонской) местности так не говорят. Я с этим словом никогда не сталкивалась.

Comment: Вполне возможно, что все эти случаи использования данного слова - все три - базируются на советском мультфильме. Словарь 99го года, перевод Джерома 2012го, книга тоже этих же лет.

Comment: спасибо за ответ